# Spark (with python) problems with withColumn

Tags: pyspark

I'm learning to use python and in my project, I specifically need to use spark.
(I'm confident with other programming languages [C++, Matlab, R] )

I want to read a csv file and as a first step, I wanted to convert the content of the columns (strings) in the proper types (date, int and double respectively).

Below is what I wrote

```
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession
from pyspark.sql.functions import udf
from pyspark.sql.types import DoubleType
from pyspark.sql.types import IntegerType
from pyspark.sql.types import DataType

spark = SparkSession.builder.appName("my_spark").getOrCreate()

# DATA PREPROCESSING


A2A_av1=spark.read.format('csv').options(header='true').load('../../Data/A2A_avail.csv')
A2A_av1.printSchema()


A2A_av1.withColumn("SUM_AVAILABLE_", A2A_av1["SUM_AVAILABLE_"].cast(DoubleType()))

A2A_av1.printSchema()
```

[Here the output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jiw8i.png), nothing changes. The column SUM_AVAILBELS_ is still a string.

Could you tell me what I'm doing wrong? Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pyspark does not offer inplace editing like pandas. so you have to assign the result to make the changes effective.Spark dataframes are immutable. change your code to

```
A2A_av1=A2A_av1.withColumn("SUM_AVAILABLE_", A2A_av1["SUM_AVAILABLE_"].cast(DoubleType()))
```

This should work :-)